# Vertically Center - with unknown height

Tags: css

I have two div's side by side. On the left is an image, on the right are inputs.

The image varies depending on what the user uploads.

How can I vertically centre align the image and the inputs? I would like the inputs to appear vertically centre to the image.

Both the img and inputs have their own container:

```
<div class="img-container">
<div class="data-container">
```

**Fiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/vbLht/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:left` and try `display` CSS Rule

```
.img-container {
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.data-container {
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vbLht/10/)

*Note:* You need to set `<!-- -->` to your mark-up after inline divs as css inline rule will leave white-space between 2 elements, Though this an awkward way but if you don't want to write that crack then you've to adjust width.

**Or**

Set your `li` style to `display:table` with the above CSS Code

```
li{
     display:table; /*remove float*/
}
.img-container {
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.data-container {
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Hope this is clear :)

Comment: Thanks, do I need display table if I take your first example?

Comment: @panthro Yes.. Acutally it's with the `display:table` Either you can set `display:table` or consider that note :)

Comment: Thanks, isn't it bad to use display: table?

Comment: @panthro See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687968/is-it-bad-use-display-table-to-organise-a-layout-into-2-columns)!

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox makes this very easy.

Just wrap the child elements you want to vertically center in a wrapper div with:

```
.wpr {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/YJZVU/2/)**

Browser support is good in modern browsers - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)..

but if CSS3 isn't an option, the `display:table` approach (As mentioned in the other answer) is fine.