# IE not coloring :before as table-cell, why?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        div:before {
            display: table-cell;
            content: "ABC";
            color: red;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>123</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd expect this to render to something like [image: expected], but I get [image: actual] instead, only when running on Internet Explorer (any version).

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: If it's to do with `display:table-cell;`, can you not change it to `display:block;`?

Comment: It worked for me: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs8Ek/).

Comment: It doesn't work in IE11 for me.

Comment: @Leo this is not a duplicate at all. Did you even read this question?

Comment: @BeatAlex my bad, I referenced the wrong link

Comment: @BeatAlex no, this is a super-simplified test case, I'm using it in a situation that requires the element to behave as a table-cell. Anyway it's probably not so important if IE gets the same color as the container element.

Comment: @ReCaptcha your fiddle renders as black on my IE10 and in IE9 emulated, can't test with IE8 since fiddle graphics are scrambled.

Comment: It does it on IE8 as well, I tested locally. @bruce965

Comment: IE ignores other styles as well (e.g. font settings) in this case.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work. I tested on Chrome. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in IE. If you inspect the element in IE 11 Developer Tools, you see all the declarations for the `:before` pseudo-element struck out (also e.g. `font` settings if you add them), but the `display` and `content` settings affect the rendering.

To circumvent this bug, it suffices in this simple case to set `display: block` as @BeatAlex suggests. In a more complicated situation, you probably need more complicated workarounds.

Comment: Appears to be resolved in the [Windows 10 Technical Preview build of Internet Explorer](http://remote.modern.ie): http://i.imgur.com/zjPl4y2.png

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a regression. It works on IE8 on Windows 7, but not IE9 or later, even in IE8 mode. Funny I didn't notice this earlier, as I remember encountering the same issue myself some time ago. I never considered something like this could possibly regress, though, much less thought of comparing the results in IE8 and IE9.

Other font-related styles are affected as well. It has been reported [before](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/796188/pseudo-element-display-table-cell-font-ignored), but there doesn't seem to have been any response other than "we're looking into it", and that was a year ago.

Workarounds include using `display: table-cell` with an actual element instead of a pseudo-element, or simply not using `display: table-cell` at all — use `display-block` instead if you don't absolutely need a table-based layout.