# Pseudo tags "before" & "after", border-left doesn't work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

I want to create a left border on a div but only on 50% of the div. I have created the following code which works in everything else than IE.
I run IE11 atm and i have tried other versions as well which shows the same error.

`Here is a Fiddle:`http://jsfiddle.net/0ffmrxpz/16/

If you remove the "display:table-cell" it will work in IE. But because of my end-design I can't remove or change this display. If I do so i break the entire design setup.

Comment: Yes, I am using the table layout to make it fit my desing. It is a combination with angularjs and I can only make it fit as I want to by using the table layout.
So there is no fix for this?

Comment: Please do not circumvent the quality filter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known interop-issue between Internet Explorer and other browsers. We have actually already began shipping changes to the underlying engine to better-render this use-case.

Below is a side-by-side of Internet Explorer 11, and our streamable *in-development* version on http://remote.modern.ie, also available in our [Windows 10 preview](http://preview.windows.com):

[image]

The primary culprit here is the use of `display: table-cell`; other than that, pseudo elements, borders, and everything else will work as expected in Internet Explorer. It's only when you use properties designed for tabular data as a layout-mechanism that you currently face this issue.

Comment: So what you are saying is, that it will be fixed in windows 10? Is there any work-around until then?

Comment: @CasperNybroe It should be fixed by Windows 10, yes. I know of no work-arounds that *use* `table-cell` layouts. I am confident that there are other approaches to accomplish whatever layout you're attempting though.

Comment: I wont be able to wait for win10. But thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: @CasperNybroe Unfortunately the only other option is to take a different design approach. I'd like to invite you to submit your design here, and we'd gladly assist with a new cross-browser method for achieving the same ends.

Comment: Do these changes address table-cell layouts and pseudo-elements as a whole? Here's a similar issue with the same root cause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693227/ie-not-coloring-before-as-table-cell-why

Comment: @BoltClock That issue also [appears to be resolved](http://i.imgur.com/zjPl4y2.png) in http://remote.modern.ie.