# Bootstrap - pull-right element creating gap in words of heading on left as screen narrows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x1aevoy9/

The problem is that as the screen narrows, the words in the `<h3>` element get big gaps between them, before finally jumping under the image. I'd like to prevent these gaps from happening, in other words keep the words together without the big gaps. It seems to happen when the second word or group of words is longer than the first word. I've played around with padding but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
h3 { display: table }
```

Comment: That worked. Why did that work? Also I read somewhere not to use tables for layout, but since this sets the display property, it should be ok, right?

Comment: This is a tricky way. but, i think, this is not considered as a good practice as it may create  [an inconsistency of certain ie versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687968/is-it-bad-use-display-table-to-organise-a-layout-into-2-columns#answer-2688000). But for similar situations, we have no other option than to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following styles to `<h3>` tag.

```
h3{
      -ms-word-break: break-all;
      word-break: break-all;

      /* Non standard for WebKit */
      word-break: break-word;

      -webkit-hyphens: auto;
      -moz-hyphens: auto;
      hyphens: auto;
}
```

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g4ar6s9r/

Comment: Thanks, but could you modify the fiddle and include it? I can't make it work.

Comment: Thanks, that's better, but it's breaking on each letter instead of each word.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. Kindly have a look @nmit026

Comment: That's quite good, but it's breaking on each individual letter rather than each word.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the two top elements in a div (the b and .pull-right)

https://jsfiddle.net/x1aevoy9/4/

```
<div>
  <b style="color:goldenrod; padding-right:5px;">Gold Member</b>
  <div class="pull-right" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
    <a href="/listings/ListingID"><img alt="Chief Bean Counter" width="160" height="120" src="listing.PhotoURL" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that worked. The gaps are still there.

Answer (score 0):

What about reorganizing your code using bootstrap columns.

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 10px;">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <b style="color:goldenrod; padding-right:5px;">Gold Member</b>
    <h3><a href="/listings/@listing.ListingID">Chief Bean Counter</a></h3>
    <p><em>This is a subtitle</em></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-5 text-right col-xs-3">
    <a href="/listings/ListingID"><img alt="Chief Bean Counter" width="160" height="120" src="listing.PhotoURL" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It snaps to a second row at a wider width that your current code, but does not interfere with the text at all.

Comment: That's good, but it puts the image under the heading and the subtitle, and doesn't have the smooth flow of the original. Thanks for your code though.